# Get meta info related to current post

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I'm trying to get the meta info by key `rw_related_link` for each post but my code is wrong since instead get the ones related to the current post I got the same in all post and that's wrong. This is what I have at `single.php`:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();       

        $normal_args   = array(
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'order'               => 'desc',
            'meta_query'          => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'rw_related_link'
                )
            ),
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'      => 6
        );

        $normal_query  = new WP_Query( $normal_args );

        if ($normal_query->have_posts()) { ?>
            <section class="single_relations sih1">
                <ul>
                    <?php while ($normal_query->have_posts()) {
                        $normal_query->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                </ul>
            </section>
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did in your code you are querying posts with the key `rw_related_link`.

If I understood you right, you must use get_post_meta inside the loop.

```
<?php while ($normal_query->have_posts()) {
          $normal_query->the_post(); 
          $related_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_related_link', true);
          // The value you want is in $related_link variable.
?>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I change my code a bit and now I get the `meta` by `rw_related_link` as follow: `$related_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_related_link', true)` that's fine, that returns an array of values and that values are the ID's of other posts, how do I get the `the_title()` and `the_permalink()` for those related posts?

Comment: Review the Codex entries for [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) - you'll note they make use of two additional functions, [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) and [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink), to which you may pass a post ID in order to retrieve the corresponding information.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments passed to [the `WP_Query` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)'s constructor are used to describe the posts you are "looking for" in, and wish to retrieve from the database - [the `'meta_query'` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) is used to retrieve posts that contain a particular meta key and/or value.

In order to actually manipulate (i.e. create/retrieve/update/delete) post meta-data, you should be using the [Metadata API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) - in this instance, [the `get_metadata()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata) in particular.

Comment: Can you take a look to the comment I leave on **@Bruno** answer? Perhaps you could help me too